# mySQL / phpMyAdmin on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, mysql, phpmyadmin

I need some help finding the right download for mySQL / phpMyAdmin for an old laptop running Windows XP.

I'm setting up a server for use in a first year high school course on Web Development; with Apache, PHP, and mySQL.

I have Apache with PHP working.

The problem is that I could only scrounge up a Windows XP system for the class server and I'm having a difficult time finding a version of mySQL with phpMyAdmin that installs on the system. 
Easy to install and configure would be great. My only previous experience with mySQL has been on a hosted service with these things already installed and maintained by others.
Everything I've tried so far bombs.

System:

Microsoft Windows XP Professional Version 2002
Service Pack 3
Intel Core2 Duo CPU
Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 Service Pack 2
Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 Service Pack 2 Language Pack - SVE
Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 Service Pack 2 
Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 Service Pack 2 Language Pack - SVE
Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1
Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile
Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile Language Pack - SVE

Comment: Phpmyadmin is OS independent it can run on any OS that MySQL and php runs on

Comment: There are different versions and only some can run on XP. That's been my experience. Newer versions of PHP don't run on XP.

Comment: i don't have that same experience

Comment: Good deal for you. As far as I can tell, my problem is about getting the right version. In all my efforts on this so far, the various download sites provide information about whether XP is supported or not. As described above, my efforts have so far been only partly successful - even while attempting to follow instructions on versions and support software provided on those sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have those last pieces running now - i.e. MySQL with phpMyAdmin. On the XP, you can use MySQL up to version 5.5 and phpMyAdmin up to version 4.4. The part of my request that was unsuccessful was "easy installation." (It wouldn't have been so bad for someone very familiar with AMP.) I'll explain main points here in case it helps someone else; but as I googled through the day to deal with each problem, I noticed a variety of answers and different responders reporting success with different answers. My general impression is that when you have problems with this stuff, it takes very little to fix it. The hard part is finding out what that "very little" is. After following instructions for installation of phpMyAdmin (unpack and place the whole upper directory in the Apache server's root application directory):

1. The Apache server needs a tmp directory.
2. session.save_path in PHP's php.ini needs to be set to the FULL PATH of the Apache server's tmp directory.
3. a copy of php.ini needs to be in C:\WINDOWS

If someone understands #3, please explain below. I'm more oriented to Java / build once, run anywhere. Why does Windows need to get involved in this?

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.alldon.info/ for how to get a complete web server with phpMyAdmin on Windows XP.

Comment: Thanks. I was just reading about that and noticed the recommendation on a similar question. This may be the way to go ultimately; but I had already put time into Apache and PHP and have those running. Are there version differences that I need to look out for - i.e. to get one that works on XP?

Comment: @Roger Xampp seems the easiest way to go for you as it automatically updates to the latest versions of each piece of software you install. It is a relatively quick installation and will have all the software that you will ever need in there, just uninstall Apache and PHP. It works on xp

Comment: I downloaded the older version (note current version doesn't work on XP or 2003 - says so on the download page). I clicked through and took the old version they said would work on XP and have tried to install it. I'm getting an already familiar error message: "xampp\php\php.exe is not a valid WIN32-program". One such message suggested that I might try installing Miccrosoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable and then executing the setup_xampp.bat in the xampp folder. I've tried that (VC++ was already installed so I repaired) and got the not valid WIN32 message while trying to run the batch file.

Comment: Neither Apache nor MySQL will start from the control panel. I get a message that they're trying but then nothing ...

Comment: @Roger not to worry. What is your system information? Have you uninstalled the previous versions of Apache and PHP?

Comment: @Roger also are you using this computer just as a web server or are you planning to do other things with it?

Comment: The system information is given above; in the question. Let me know if something else is needed. I have not uninstalled the other software. I disabled the services for them. (I may need to fall back to them, and don't want to start over.) This computer will be used as a server only. I also installed Tomcat 7 and JDK 7 (8 doesn't support XP) and the FileZilla server so that I can upload changes easily. The old Tomcat was also disabled and the new Tomcat w XAMPP started without problem.

Comment: @Roger so is your problem fixed? You are using it just as a server, so do you want to use Linux instead because it will be much more powerful then. If you want to do this instead, just ask

Comment: I was just guessing that would be your next question. I've done that with my old XPs; but this computer belongs to the school system, so I'm not taking such liberties. Maybe I can ask; but really - all I need is a version of MySQL with a good control panel (I no longer care if it's phpMyAdmin). I already had a good install on Apache and PHP and all the other stuff.

Comment: admin tool .... you know what I mean

Comment: @RogerF.Gay See my edited answer

Comment: @RogerF.Gay please mark my answer as correct if it helps you

Comment: I upped you from -1 to 0. Someone -1'd us both. :( The solution wasn't that easy, but with a full day's work, I licked it. I'm going to post my own solution. Yours would have been great if it had worked. I tried and it didn't. XP is no longer supported, so this has just been a pain. I installed much as you described on two other computers where I'll likely do development without difficulty.

Comment: @Roger was the website ok I gave you?

Comment: I guess the website was ok, but it didn't solve the problem. I think it's one I visited before posting. btw: XAMPP was a good suggestion, even though it  didn't solve the current problem. Now that I've seen it, I may install it on another computer. I've spent years using Tomcat, and have wanted to try Apache with Tomcat. XAMPP looks like a whole ready-to-use shopping center.

Comment: @RogerF.Gay ok that's fine, if you do not write an answer yourself please do acknowledge that my answer helped by accepting it. Thanks